# MySQL; the function value doesn't appear in resulted table

Tags: mysql

I created a table with three fields and applied a created function to automatic concat two fields of the same record and the result appears in the third field of the table at the same record. 
While the problem is whenever I do insert statement the result of the function appears as error but not on the table!!! the following is the code:

```
create table Tab (
  stuId varchar (1), 
  stuName varchar (10)
  recordCon varchar (20), 
  primary key (stuId));
```

Auto concat function for one record by input id:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION AutoCon (id varchar (1)) RETURNS int DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE name varchar(10);
 DECLARE Con varchar(20);

 select stuName from Tab where stuId = id into name; 
 Select concat(id, name) into con;
 RETURN con; 
END 
//
DELIMITER ;
```

```
insert into Tab values ('1a', 'Rami', AutoCon('1a'))
```

the result

```
a1  Rami    null
```

Answer (score 0):

`FUNCTION AutoCon (id varchar (1))`, but you pass 2 chars as the parameter - `AutoCon('1a')`

Something wrong there ...

Comment: by mistake, I add (1)

Comment: Great news!  You should post - and accept - your own answer. Glad you found it :-)

Comment: If you post & accept an answer, it will help others who read this question in future

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Does it still give the same error when you change the parameter to `varchar(2)`? Or is there now  a new error?